# I am having issues with nestjs-i18n when running on Cloud Function

Tags: google-cloud-functions, nestjs, nestjs-i18n

It seems like you are encountering an issue with nestjs-i18n when running on Cloud Functions. When you make the first API call after building the source, the I18nModule is always initialized after the API has completed, resulting in a 404 error.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBcne.png

I want the I18nModule to always be initialized before the request is logged.